# How mongo chooses which chunk to move

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've tried to move some chunks from one shard to another to remove the read hot spot. I did the following:

1. stopped automatic balancing `sh.stopBalancer()`
2. moved some chunks from 1 shard to another with sh.moveChunk. After this, the destination shard contains more shards, then the others.
3. Started automatic balancing back `sh.startBalancer()`

After restarting of automating balancing the same chunks, that were just moved manually, were returned back to the shard the were copied from.

How can I disable them from moving back and what is the algorithm, mongo uses to decide, which chunk will move during the next balancing round?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to move data manually and prevent the balancing operation of only some chunks?

Comment: The clustering key used due to its "range" nature, leads to a data being poorly distributed. Most of the time all the customer data resides on a single shard, but some of the customers are pretty big and I'd like to spread their data among some more shards.

Comment: Ok, then why not choose a better sharding key?

Comment: The database is very big and resharding at this stage is not feasible

Comment: As long as the balancer is running you cannot prevent a chunk from moving. Chunks move when shards are not balanced regarding the number of chunks. I don't see much options here: change the sharding key or  perform the balancing manually. Either way, both are quite painful.

Comment: This is the root of the problem: I moved chunk manually, but automatic balancer chooses this chunk and moves it back. This is what I'm trying to understand: how mongodb decides which chunk will be moved and why its choosing my chunk to move it back and not any other chunk

Comment: Questions like this belong to http://dba.stackexchange.com - I nominated this question for migration.